# Subtract values from SELECT in SQL

Tags: foxpro, xbase

I have the following 2 queries.:

1. `shipManagementInvoiceNetValue`:

   ```
   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (shipManagementInvoice.netto ), 0) AS shipManagementInvoiceNetValue
   FROM tckopf AS shipManagementInvoice
   WHERE shipManagementInvoice.referenzid = 1
       AND shipManagementInvoice.btyp = 5
   ```
2. `shipManagementCreditNoteNetValue`:

   ```
   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (shipManagementCreditNote.netto), 0) AS shipManagementCreditNoteNetValue
   FROM tckopf AS shipManagementCreditNote
   WHERE shipManagementCreditNote.referenzid = 1
       AND shipManagementCreditNote.btyp = 6
   ```

but I need the result `shipManagementInvoiceNetValue - shipManagementCreditNoteNetValue`. I'm using a [HXTT JDBC DBF driver](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf/) that supports [more than SQL92](http://www.hxtt.com/dbf.html).

How can I realize that?

Comment: `SELECT (queryA) - (queryB) AS NameYourResultColumn;` would do I think.

Comment: SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN btyp = 6 THEN netto ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN btyp = 5 THEN netto ELSE 0 END) FROM tckopf WHERE referenzid = 1; might also work in a single query.

Comment: @ypercube thanks, `SELECT (queryA) - (queryB) AS NameYourResultColumn;` works.

Comment: @capnhector That would work, too.

Comment: @WindRaven `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN btyp = 6 THEN netto ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN btyp = 5 THEN netto ELSE 0 END) FROM tckopf WHERE referenzid = 1` seems to work too. Also, I can bypass [this bug](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58841/how-to-ifnull-or-coalesce-rewrite-in-a-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this..

```
SELECT X.shipManagementInvoiceNetValue - Y.shipManagementCreditNoteNetValue
FROM 
(
   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (shipManagementInvoice.netto ), 0) AS shipManagementInvoiceNetValue
   FROM tckopf AS shipManagementInvoice
   WHERE shipManagementInvoice.referenzid = 1
   AND shipManagementInvoice.btyp = 5
)X,
(
   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (shipManagementCreditNote.netto), 0) AS shipManagementCreditNoteNetValue
   FROM tckopf AS shipManagementCreditNote
   WHERE shipManagementCreditNote.referenzid = 1
   AND shipManagementCreditNote.btyp = 6
)Y
```