# How to IFNULL or COALESCE rewrite in a SQL query?

Tags: jdbc, foxpro

I there a way to rewrite a SQL query, so I can avoid `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`, because the HXTT DBF JDBC driver (supports SQL92) throws the following error.:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The aggregate function SUM(NETTO) can only be used in select-list, HAVING clause, and ORDER BY clause of SELECT statement.
```

The following query causes the above error.:

```
SELECT
(   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (shipManagementInvoice.netto ), 0) AS shipManagementInvoiceNetValue
    FROM tckopf AS shipManagementInvoice
    WHERE shipManagementInvoice.referenzid = 1
        AND shipManagementInvoice.btyp = 5 )
-
(   SELECT IFNULL (SUM (shipManagementCreditNote.netto), 0) AS shipManagementCreditNoteNetValue
    FROM tckopf AS shipManagementCreditNote
    WHERE shipManagementCreditNote.referenzid = 1
        AND shipManagementCreditNote.btyp = 6 )
 AS shipManagementResult
```

If I remove `IFNULL` or `COALESCE`, there is no error.

Comment: Did you try the answer by Shahid in the previous question? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58673/subtract-values-from-select-in-sql

Comment: Yes, I get the same error.

Comment: I don't understand the position of your `IFNULL`. Surely it should be *outside* the subquery? Something like `SELECT IFNULL((SELECT ...), 0) - IFNULL((SELECT ...), 0)`.

Comment: @Colin'tHart It is needed for when the summation goes over an empty table (no rows with `btyp=5` for example). It could be moved outside though for a scalar subquery like this one.

Comment: Right, it's aggregating over all rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to rewrite the query and even more because both subqueries use the same base table. Not sure why the error is thrown and who is to blame, the JDBC drivers, the Foxpro or something else, so here are a few alternatives:

- (1) using one query for both searches:

  ```
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t.btyp = 5 THEN t.netto
                           WHEN t.btyp = 6 THEN - t.netto 
                                           ELSE 0 
                      END), 0) AS shipManagementResult
  FROM tckopf AS t
  WHERE t.referenzid = 1 ;
  ```
- (2) pulling the `COALESCE()` or `IFNULL()` function call in the external level, either using the original query:

  ```
  SELECT 
    COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(i.netto) 
                FROM tckopf AS i
                WHERE i.referenzid = 1
                  AND i.btyp = 5 
              ), 0)
  - COALESCE( ( SELECT SUM(c.netto) 
                FROM tckopf AS c
                WHERE c.referenzid = 1
                  AND c.btyp = 6 
              ), 0)
    AS shipManagementResult ;
  ```
- (2b) or the above (1st) query:

  ```
  SELECT COALESCE( 
    ( SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.btyp = 5 THEN t.netto
                      WHEN t.btyp = 6 THEN - t.netto 
                                      ELSE 0 
                  END)
      FROM tckopf AS t
      WHERE t.referenzid = 1
    ), 0) AS shipManagementResult ;
  ```

Comment: The first one does not work, but second works.

Comment: I have to correct me, (2b) works, but it gives me the result also for document with `WHERE t.referenzid != 1`. That is not the case with [this query](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58864/27568)

Comment: What do you mean? That if there is no row with `referenzid = 1`, it answers with `0`? That's how it should work, I thought that's why you used `COALESCE()` and `ISNULL()` in the first place.

Comment: A document has a `document_id`, in the above example `1` and a `referenzid`. I use it in a Jasper report. I pass the `document_id` to a subreport, to find all documents that have the `1` as `referenzid`. Also there is the `btyp` filter. In the (2b), I get other documents, where `btyp && referenzid` is not `true`.

Comment: If you get other documents, then you probably use this as a subquery, inside some other query.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58673/subtract-values-from-select-in-sql/58717#comment105941_58673) does also work.:

```
SELECT SUM ( CASE WHEN btyp = 6 THEN netto ELSE 0 END) - SUM(CASE WHEN btyp = 5 THEN netto ELSE 0 END)
FROM tckopf
WHERE referenzid = 1;
```

Comment: yes, but if you have zero rows with `referenzid = 1`, then the result will be `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

try `ISNULL(SUM (shipManagementInvoice.netto ), 0)`

Comment: Why? That is what I want to avoid.